# How to split 1 column in excel into 2 separate columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

**Question**

Given a single column of weight_and_units which looks something like:

```
weight_and_units
10Ounces
10Ounces
10Ounces
10Ounces
10Ounces
10Pounds
10Pounds
10Pounds
10Pounds
10Pounds
11Ounces
11Ounces
11Ounces
11Ounces
11Ounces
11Pounds
11Pounds
11Pounds
11Pounds
11Pounds
12Ounces
12Ounces
12Ounces
12Ounces
12Ounces
```

I want to be able to create 2 separate columns like

```
weight
10
11
12
13
```

and

```
units
Ounces
Pounds
Pounds
```

**Tried**

I have looked into the process outlined in this link: [Creating 2 columns from 1](https://spreadsheetplanet.com/split-one-column-into-multiple-columns-excel/) however this seems to only work for a column which has a set delimiter etc and as a result I don't think it would work in this scenario.

Any method (ideally the simplest) to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance to play with left() and right() formulas? I mean units or the values do they have fixed length?

Comment: Well the units in this case are either Pounds or Ounces where as the weight can vary from a single digit to two or even three digits typically

Comment: In this case it could be simple Units can be obtained by right(a1, 6) and weight can be left(a1, len(a1)-6. However, more generic solution I have posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am gonna tell you the simplest method using the flash fill without any formulas. This will work for any number of digits

Just fill the data manually in for the first line like the below,

| Weight and Unit | Weight | Ounces |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10Ounces | 10 | Ounces |
| 10Pounds |  |  |
| 10Pounds |  |  |
| 10Pounds |  |  |
| 11Pounds |  |  |

**Step1:**
Select the cell Weight and Click **Ctrl + E** to fill the Weight Column.

**Step2:**
Select the cell Unit and Click **Ctrl + E** to fill the Unit Column.

*Output:*

| Weight and Unit | Weight | Ounces |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10Ounces | 10 | Ounces |
| 10Pounds | 10 | Pounds |
| 10Pounds | 10 | Pounds |
| 10Pounds | 10 | Pounds |
| 11Pounds | 11 | Pounds |

*More info on Flash fill:*

Data -> Data Tools -> Flash Fill

[image: Flash Fill]

Comment: Great thanks, do you know how the flash fill is able to detect the pattern?

Comment: @nishcs Flash fill analyses patten of the data filled in, more examples are here https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/03/06/flash-fill-excel-examples/

Answer (score 1):

**For Number**

LEFT(A1,SUM(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},""))))

**For Text**

RIGHT(A1, Len(the above value)

Answer (score 1):

In column B:

=LEFT(A2;MATCH(TRUE;ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)));1)));0)-1)

In column C:

=MID(A2;FIND(B2;A2;1)+2;50)

Answer (score 1):

I liked the flash-fill option but if you go with formulas you could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(A2,ROW($1:$99)))
```

Formula in `C2`:

```
=MID(A2,LEN(B2)+1,99)
```